# How Do I Configure launch.json for a Java App in VS Code with a Different Current Directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I need a Java application in VS Code to have a specific working directory.  I added the `cwd` property to my launch.json, but then end up with classPath problems.  This application uses gradle to pull in several dependencies for Spring, Lombok, Apache Commons, etc.

After adding the `cwd` and `classPaths` properties as shown below, I end up with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
        at com.example.BatchAutomationApplication.main(BatchAutomationApplication.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 1 more
```

How do I add the gradle dependencies to the classPath?

### launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch) - Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch)-BatchAutomationApplication<batch-processing>",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "com.example.BatchAutomationApplication",
            "projectName": "batch-processing",
            "cwd": "C:\\dev\\logs",
            "classPaths": ["${workspaceFolder}\\bin\\main"]
        }
    ]
}
```